# Error when editing content query web part

Tags: sharepoint, office365, web-parts, sharepoint-online

I'm working on SharePoint Online.

I want to edit a CQWP, but I get an error from Microsoft SharePoint Foundation:

> Troubleshooting of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation identifier: 5a4a6f9d-20cd-3000-9f42-29e549e6ddfe

This is at Site Collection level, since the problem occurs anywhere in my collection.

Answer (score 0):

Open the logs on the server and search for your correlation id: this will give you (mostly) a clearer error message. Paste it here and then we can try to help you because now we are like a blind man trying to find a stick :)

hint: this tool will can improve the filtering of the logs: https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/